# How to use MediaCodec to decode data from RTSP server?

Tags: android, rtsp, android-mediacodec

I tried `setDataSource()` in `MediaExtractor` class but it doesn't work with RTSP path. I can use the same path with `MediaPlayer` class and it works but it is very important for me to use `MediaCodec` class instead. I think Android doesn't have any RTSP API I could use nor I can find any RTSP libraries for Android.

Is there a relatively easy way of feeding video stream from RTSP server into `MediaCodec` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No easy way. I ended up using this project:

> https://code.google.com/p/android-rtsp-client/

for RTSP protocol (worked after some fixes and modifications).

I needed to implement RTP and RTCP protocols myself (some simplified versions were enough in my case).

I also needed to create a code for extracting NAL units from RTP packets. I had to read this first:

> http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt

to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Can you give some insight on how exactly you took the RTSP stream from the above Android project and fed it into a `MediaCodec` decoder?  I'm a bit outside of my element here, and this is part of the application I need to develop for my employer.  Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Fwiw, RFC 3984 has been superseded by RFC 6184 - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184.

Comment: Has anything changed since 2013?