# Example code to decode rtsp stream using MediaCodec

Tags: android

Can someone give some example code about using MediaCodec to decode a rtsp stream, I read document and find too much but no luck. It seems MediaCodec is hard to use and not popular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use MediaCodec to decode data from RTSP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994837/how-to-use-mediacodec-to-decode-data-from-rtsp-server)

Comment: I've read this topic but it doesn't have what I need :(